# Left Join - attempting to identify instances where child records do not exist, or if they do exist, populate unique records meeting specific criteria

Tags: sql, join, subquery, left-join

I am attempting to search an SQL database for instances where child records do not exist, or if they do exist, they are a specific type (e.g. Historical) and no other types exist (e.g. Current):

```
SELECT distinct parent.id FROM parenttable 
Left Join childtable On childtable.primarykey = parenttable.primarykey 
Where childtable.id is null
```

This populates all of my parent records that do not have any child records without any issues. However, I also want the query to populate instances where the **only** child records that exist are historical (e.g. childtable.type = 'Historical'). I have not been able to do this thus far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `not exists`:

```
select p.id 
from parenttable p
where not exists (
    select 1
    from childtable c
    where c.primarykey = p.primarykey and c.type <> 'Historical'
)
```

This phrases as: get all records from the parent table that have no child whose type is other than "Historical" - parents without a child do satisfy this condition too.

Comment: Thanks - this worked. However, if a child record exists where they c.type is null for a current record, it populates the parent record still. Would it be possible to adjust it so if the c.type is null on a current record, it will not populate the parent record?

Answer (score 0):

Try this please (using operator In):

```
SELECT id FROM parenttab WHERE primarykey NOT IN
(SELECT primarykey FROM childtable WHERE type<>'Historical'
 OR type IS NULL)
```

It is more fast than to find a match for every row in subquery